# Given M, can we find $2$ primes $a,b$ so that for all naturals $x,y$, $|a^x-b^y|>M$?

Tags: number-theory

For example, if $M = 2$, one can show that $3,17$ satisfy the above:

For any naturals $x,y$, $|3^x-17^y|>2$.

Comment: Can $x=y$ then its somewhat easy

Comment: I'm not sure I follow,$x=y$ is allowed but not required.

Comment: I think if you find two primes such that $|a^1-b^1|>M$ then any $|n|$ multiplied by it will always give a positive result where $n\in N$

Comment: You mean multiply $a$ and $b$ by $n$? Then they won't be prime.
Also this example may help:
$|2-7| = 5$ but $|2^3-7|=1$

Comment: No $|2^3-7^3|=335$

Comment: Like I said, I don't require x=y, which is why they have different letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $a$ to be a prime larger than $M + 1$, and let $b$ be the first prime congruent to $1 \pmod{2 \cdot a}$, guaranteed to exist by Dirichlet's theorem.  Now $a^x \equiv a \pmod{2 \cdot a}$ and $b^y \equiv 1 \pmod{2 \cdot a}$, so $\vert a^x - b^y \vert \ge a-1 \gt M$.  Using this method, for $M=3$ we have $(a,b)=(5,11)$, $5^x \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$, and $11^y \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$.  In other words $5^x = \dots 5$ and $11^y = \dots 1$, so they differ by at least $4$.

Comment: Lovely! I love the trick of a^x = a mod (2*a), I'm going to use it for more stuff :)